# Data from JSON response not displaying after assigning to instance variable

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ajax

So, I have my SPA at about 98% functional.  The app pulls data from a MySQL database and allows the user to edit/delete records.  For the page in question, it will edit/delete data of the specified student ID but it will not properly display the data in the text fields.

If you do not input a value it will display the first item in the JSON array but not the one you specify in the search field.

I did not do a very good job at explaining that but here is the HTML page that uses a function to pass data to the controller which then selects the corresponding student by ID and assigns it to the variable $scope.student.  I then try to display the student data on the HTML page by using student.first_name (or any property) but it does not work correctly.

```
<h3>Edit/Delete Student with ID: {{student.student_id}}</h3>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="sid">Student ID:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="sid" ng-model="sid">
</div>

<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getRecord(sid)"> 
Get Student Info </button> </p>

<div class='row'>

<div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" ng-model="student.first_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" ng-model="student.last_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="hrs_completed">Hrs Completed:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hrs_completed" ng-model= "student.hrs_completed">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="hrs_attempted">Hrs Attempted:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hrs_attempted" ng-model= "student.hrs_attempted">
    </div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="gpa_points">GPA Points:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gpa_points" ng-model= "student.gpa_points">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="major">Major:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="major" ng-model="student.major">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="advisor_id">Advisor ID:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="advisor_id" ng-model="student.advisor_id">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" ng-model="student.email">
    </div>

</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateRecord()">Update</button> &nbsp;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteRecord()">Delete</button>
```

And here is my controller on my Javascript page:

```
app.controller('editCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get("getStudentData.php")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.students = response.data;
    });

$scope.getRecord = function(sid) {
    id = sid;

    $scope.student = $scope.students.find(s=>s.id == sid);

};
```

Do I need to make a seperate GET request to the server for this to work properly or do I just need to reference the student object differently?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. _"it does not work correctly"_ is not a problem description

Comment: The data for an individual student does not populate the text fields on my html page. I can access the student by typing an id in and editing or deleting he data but it will not DISPLAY in the text boxes after executing the function (pressing the button).

Comment: What debugging have you done? Are there any errors in your console? When your code executes `getRecord()`, are there entries in `$scope.students`? Do any of them match the ID passed in to the function?

Comment: Yes $scope.students contains the entire students table as a json response.  I then just then to match the sid sent with the function to a student id and display the data in the text fields.  I thought I had the correct code to assign the single student object to $scope.student but I guess I do not because when I reference it on the html the fields are blank.

Comment: So exactly what **is** being assigned to `$scope.student` in `getRecord()`? If it's `undefined`, then your [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) callback is not matching anything. **Are there any errors in your console?**

Comment: There are no errors in the console.  $scope.student is being assigned the first object in the JSON response no matter what.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170052/discussion-between-daniel-miller-and-phil).

Comment: Did my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is mismatch in what you are getting as `response.data` and what you are trying to `.find()` and then what you are binding on html.

[Check this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BrqVUhuH7HK9bXFJlpMX?p=preview).

You are trying to render by searching `id` property.

```
$scope.students.find(s=>s.id == sid);
```

where as you are rendering on UI using `student_id` property.

```
{{student.student_id}}
```

So, surely there is mismatch in what you are getting as `response.data` and what you are rendering using `$scope.student` properties. I think my plunkr will show that your function is correct.

In case this answer doesn't work, share your `response.data`.